# Taildwind con react js

Tags: reactjs, tailwind

tengo una duda, puedo guardar la clase "active" que pertenece a talwind en una variable??? y esta mediante el atributo style asignarla???

sucede lo siguiente, quiero que cuando seleccione una opcion esta se muestra activa en pantalla, esto lo estoy haciendo en react js con tailwind, actualmente estoy guardando en una variable usestate cuando el doy click sobre el boton: aqui el codigo:

```
const [ActiveOne, setActiveOne] = useState("");
const [ActiveTwo, setActiveTwo] = useState("");
const [ActiveThree, setActiveThree] = useState("");

function OptionSelected(param){
    switch(param){
        case 1:
            return( 
                    setActiveOne("active"), 
                    setActiveTwo(""),
                    setActiveThree(""),
                    setTypeMessage(1) 
            );
        case 2:
            return( 
                    setActiveOne(""), 
                    setActiveTwo("active"),
                    setActiveThree(""),
                    setTypeMessage(2) 
            );
        case 3:
            return( 
                    setActiveOne(""), 
                    setActiveTwo(""),
                    setActiveThree("active"), 
                    setTypeMessage(3) 
            );                                 
        default:
            return( 
                    setActiveOne("active"), 
                    setActiveTwo(""),
                    setActiveThree(""),
                    setTypeMessage(1)                
            )
    }
}

            <div className="col-span-6 flex flex-row content-center justify-start">
                <div className={`"box-content-icon-ts flex flex-wrap content-center justify-center"  ${ActiveOne}`}>
                    <button onClick={()=>OptionSelected(1)} > 
                        <i className="bi bi-chat-square-dots-fill text-purple text-base"></i> 
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className={`"box-content-icon-ts flex flex-wrap content-center justify-center ml-2" ${ActiveTwo}`}>
                    <button onClick={()=>OptionSelected(2)}>
                        <i className="bi bi-envelope-fill text-orange text-base"></i>
                    </button>    
                </div>
                <div className={`"box-content-icon-ts flex flex-wrap content-center justify-center ml-2" ${ActiveThree}`}>
                    <button onClick={()=>OptionSelected(3)}>
                        <i className="bi bi-mic-fill text-cyan text-base"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

esto esta funcionando, pero tengo el inconveniente que se deforman los botones, de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta perdiendo en padding..

Answer (score 0):

La variable active en tailwind es un prefijo que sirve para añadir ciertos estilos cuando cierto elemento es activado, en este caso botones clicados.
No viene activada por defecto y debes añadirlo en el archivo de configuración por cada propiedad que quieras usar (Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states).

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['active'],
    }
  },
}
```

Sí se puede asignar a una variable y utilizarla en el style, pero dado para lo que se usa active en tailwind no debería ser necesario añadirla, deberías simplemente declararla y ya funcionaría con el efecto que quieres en el momento que es activado, ejemplo:

```
active:border-gray-300
```

En tu caso de uso parece que quieres además que el estado de activado persista una vez se ha realizado la acción, lamentablemente creo que la clase active no te serviría y es mejor guardarlo en un estado, en vez de realizarlo en tres estados con uno debería ser suficiente:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(1);

const handleClick = (buttonNumber) => {
    setActive(buttonNumber);
}
```

Luego que se añada condicionalmente las clases que tienes en los componentes, no es necesario añadir comillas dobles cuando usas `` en js ya que se considera que eso ya es un string por lo que quedaría para el primero (el resto sería igual):

```
<div 
className={`box-content-icon-ts flex flex-wrap content-center justify-center  ${active == 1 ? "active-class" : "" }`}>
       <button onClick={()=>handleClick(1)} > 
            <i className="bi bi-chat-square-dots-fill text-purple text-base"></i> 
       </button>
</div>
```

Dado que los botones son prácticamente iguales (solo cambia color e icono), quizás podrías como recomendación sacar un componente para todos ellos para evitar repetir el mismo código.